# China quantum telecom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

Perhaps did you read this information :

[China’s Latest Leap Forward Isn’t Just Great—It’s Quantum](http://www.wsj.com/articles/chinas-latest-leap-forward-isnt-just-greatits-quantum-1471269555)

> Beijing launches the world’s first quantum-communications satellite
>   into orbit
>
> State media said China sent the world’s **first quantum-communications**
>   satellite into orbit from a launch center in Inner Mongolia about 1:40
>   a.m. Tuesday. **Five years in the making**, the project is being closely
>   watched in global scientific and security circles.
>
> The quantum program is the latest part of China’s multibillion-dollar
>   strategy over the past two decades to draw even with or surpass the
>   West in hard-sciences research.

**main question** : Is this project credible in regard of the state of the art as known in the universities?

Not important optional question : As for the d-wave solution, must we classify quantum computation and cryptonics as *technologies* which will be as such, shrouded in secrecy ?

You may answer that it is not the *classical* $q$-cryptography that is described in, for example, wikipedia. If so, what are the new principles?

edit : to answer to the relevant Zeldredge comment: sending a satellite is plausible, nobody doubts. But this implies to have an efficient technology, here, since at least 5 years. Following nearly all the informations on the subject, I don't see how a team got this technology 5 years ago in secret ! As today, a lot of engineers which spent a lot of time ( and money ), helped by great profs of great universities, didn't succeed to establish a valid protocol of communication ( as the theory we know states ). The alternate not polite question is , *Is it not some kind of bluff ?* or merely just a weak quantum application. By analogy with d-Wave which is not able to do *today* what we wait from a Quantum computer.

Comment: There's a paywall on the article. Can you provide a summary?

Comment: no paywall from Europe, I'll update the post. I don't care about secret. What is the state of this art ? this may imply an open door on thousands of new ideas ( I recycle comments to minimize their quantities )

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking precisely. If your question is whether a quantum-communication satellite is technologically viable, the answer is yes, this satellite is real (or at least seems quite plausible). If you'd like to know about the applications and security implications of quantum information technology, perhaps ask that directly as a separate question.

Comment: @zeldredge : for me , the state of the art in teleportation is not clear. Many experiments has different conclusions and many new ones are in preparation with big grants. It is a subject similar to the irruption of d-Wave in the quantum computation, no one ( or at least me :) ) knows exactly how they do

Comment: This [wikipedia page of quantum networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_network) worth reading. Also notice, since the year 2003 goverments had been using operational and functional quantum networks. According to this wikipage, there are 5 in the world right now (one of them, in china). Apparently, China has decided to expand it a little bit (to space)......

Comment: @Physicist137 : *Due to the properties of QM and the no-cloning theorem, it is impossible for an eavesdropper to determine the key without being detected by the sender and receiver.* : this part of the protocols had never been implemented ( and checked as working with entangled photons ). This page speaks mainly about projects of some kinds of laboratories.

Comment: @igael They have been implemented..... Or at least.. its what wiki says... If you continue the reading immediately after your quote: *While the BB84 protocol relies on the superposition of qubit states to detect eavesdropping [...]*. Looking the [table down below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_network#Current_status), we see all 5 networks has BB84 protocol implemented. As the title of the table is very clear: *Major quantum network projects and QKD protocols implemented*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best possible answer to your question is given in [this Nature News article.](http://www.nature.com/news/chinese-satellite-is-one-giant-step-for-the-quantum-internet-1.20329?WT.mc_id=TWT_NatureNews) As the article explains in detail, this type of technology has been established before, and indeed it doesn't require a special "quantum satellite":

> Last year, the team showed that photons bounced back to Earth off an existing satellite maintained their quantum states and were received with low enough error rates for quantum cryptography

What this satellite does have is an on-board source of entanglement (I believe a single-photon parametric down converter):

> At the heart of their satellite is a crystal that produces pairs of entangled photons

As to how they did this, there's no secret Chinese intelligence going on here that the rest of the world wasn't aware of. They just were willing to put up the money for it. The article goes into some of the organizational details, notes that Anton Zeilinger (European) is a major part of the collaboration, and details some other efforts that have taken place around the world.

Comment: a better link ! could I refer to it in the question please ? That makes feel better seeing the names

Comment: @igael The intention of the site is that questions are asked and then have definitive answers, rather than working like a discussion forum. If you want to point people toward the link and feel it answers the question, the best you could do is accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This marks the question as answered. Otherwise, you continually edit the question and the answers become superfluous.

Comment: I asked your choice politely and i'll respect it ! You know , in general, I'm not qualified to say if a question is well answered. I downvote rarely but I trust the community. However, in this particular case, the questions are very precise for someone which works in the domain : how they do the impossible ? What will you think if tomorrow you read on your favorite newspaper that Strangersland realized a water engine ? To laugh or to be afraid ?

Comment: @igael Well, in general the idea is that you asked the question, so you decide whether it is answered :) admittedly, this is not a great answer from a SE perspective because it's mostly a reference, but I hope it cleared up the scientific context of this -- it certainly isn't "out of nowhere" and as an expert I wasn't surprised to see it (though I am excited)

Comment: @igael As far as I know, the key technology to achieve the control of photons have been tested a few years ago through free space on ground with a  distance of 100km. So now they just put the equipment on the satellite to test if it will work under a different scenario.

Comment: @X.Dong: I'm just a numerical checker. Our team asks for raw datas and analyze them. Until today, after more than 40 photons experiments studies, we don't found any proof of that is working. At the opposite, we got recently a study with electrons which is convincing. Then, what is this announce ? who is the bluffed one ?

Comment: I must add, that just not knowing something is not a proof of non existence ! but, all the claims are based on some experiments we have analyzed and found that their conclusions ( and sometimes their analytical methods ) were questionable.

Comment: @igael Do you mean the reliable long distance distribution of entangled photons, or photon based teleportation experiments?  Are you familiar with the strategy used in this work, or you also have checked their experimental data? I am not familiar of experimental works.

Comment: @igael The experimental verification of photon based teleportation has a history of almost 20 years. Do you mean that according to your analysis, all those works are not really holding water?  Or it's not reliable for long distance experiments but OK for short distance?

Comment: @X.Dong: yes we have. Each experiment conclusion don't say a lot. Put together , and it is an opinion, there is an emergent and very stange phenomena of beleif. Any physicist which don't agree is moked even if Nobel awarded. Try yourself :  it become easier to get datas since it is more than previously , a condition to get some grants.

Comment: OK. But if the electron based experiment is promising, then this at least can help to show that QC is not something just imaginary. But I do wish their experiment can work this time.